# Magento : Products not showing in Product Sitemap (catalog/seo_sitemap/product/ )

Tags: magento, sitemap, catalog

Well we are not able to get the products to display in the product sitemap which is by default available in magento at (http://sitename.com/catalog/seo_sitemap/product/).

We have the following code present in the  app/design/frontendbase/default/template/catalog/seo/sitemap.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Seo_Sitemap_
 */
?>
<?php $_items = $this->getCollection(); ?>

<?  //var_dump($_items);?>

<?php if($_items->getSize()): ?>
    <ul class="sitemap">
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getItemUrl($_item) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->name) ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="note-msg">
        <?php echo $this->__('There are no %s available.', $this->getItemsTitle()); ?>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        if ($('sitemap_top_links') != undefined) {
            $('sitemap_top_links').hide();
        }
    //]]>
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

We tried to var_dump($_items) the product sitemap page and we were able to get the data dump of product however $_items->getSize() returns 0 and the foreach is not able to parse the $_items array.

Is there a magento backend setting or a product attribute that controls the sitemap behavior. Also the category sitemap seems to be working fine so the issue is specific to products.